# Print As The While Loop Iterates

Tags: php, while-loop

Consider the following code:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 100)
{
    echo $i."<br>";
    sleep(3);
    $i++;
}
```

Here PHP prints numbers all at once. Why it doesn't stop after printing 1 then sleeping for 3 secs and then printing next number ? Is there any way to print numbers after a specific time (3 seconds in this case) ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to flush PHP's output buffers after each iteration to get the result you want to have.

Try the following;
add `flush();` above your sleep call.

If that doesnt work, add `ob_flush();` above that same `flush();`
Example:

```
$i=1;
while($i > 0)
{
    echo $i;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep($delay);
    $i--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for you:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 3)
{
    flush();
    echo $i."<br>";
    sleep(3);
    ob_flush();
    $i++;
}
```